# React Native Social Login Using PassportJS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native

Implemented as backend and expo of the following links:
https://medium.com/@ehlinger.matt/oauth-linkedin-react-native-passport-js-setup-9f707f18f57e

In my project, we need to do a React-Native of Android and iOS, not Expo.
import { AuthSession, WebBrowser, Linking } from 'expo'; How should I change?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn';
import { Linking} from 'react-native';
```